# Unexpected character encountered(Where can I find the unexpected character?)

Tags: c#

I keep getting this error...

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value:<. Path '', line 0, 
position 0-
```

My question is where I can find the unexpected character? Or how do I fix my code? The error occurs at the return Json.Convert for both GetOpenPositions and GetOpenOrders. Thanks!

```
namespace BitMEX
{
public class OrderBookItem
{
public string Symbol { get; set; }
public int Level { get; set; }
public int BidSize { get; set; }
public decimal BidPrice { get; set; }
public int AskSize { get; set; }
public decimal AskPrice { get; set; }
public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
}

public List<Position> GetOpenPositions(string symbol)
{
    var param = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string res = Query("GET", "/position", param, true);
    return (dynamic)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Position>>
(res).Where(a => a.Symbol == symbol && a.IsOpen == true).OrderByDescending(a 
=> a.TimeStamp).ToList();

}

public List<Order> GetOpenOrders(string symbol)
{
    var param = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    param["symbol"] = symbol;
    param["reverse"] = true.ToString();
    string res = Query("GET", "/order", param, true);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Order>>(res).Where(a => 
 a.OrdStatus == "New" || a.OrdStatus 
 =="PartiallyFilled").OrderByDescending(a => a.TimeStamp).ToList();

}
```

Comment: Hard to see if you don't actually post the json. Though if you have a file starting with `<`, are you sure it's json and not xml? Try dumping the result of your `Query` and seeing what's actually in there; might be something like an html error page.

Comment: [You just asked this a little while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48628099/1070452) - why the repost?

Comment: Please update your post with the value of `res`.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it is trying to parse an XML because of `<`. Json string should start with `{` or `[`

```
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
    Unexpected character encountered while parsing value:<. Path '', line 0, 
    position 0-
```